# Feature importance changed while I am running a saved model to score new dataset

Tags: random-forest

I am using a stored Random forest model ( in a pickle file) to score a new dataset. When I am pulling out the feature importance again, I see a change in the values and rank ordering among features. Shouldn't the feature importance remain same as the base model is the same and not changing. Am I missing something here

I re trained the model to check if someone had overwritten the model or something. But the numbers still change.

Comment: There could be some reasons behind it. Can you please post your code, my suspicion would be that you are no specifiying a random seed for the partitions, and therefore you get different results each time you run your code